# How do you use the Devise (rails) endpoint in swift?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, devise, registration

I'm using the devise rails gem for my user model and I would like to know how to use their registration end point passing in the username, password, and password_confirmation in a swift app.

Then endpoint normally directs you to a web form asking for the credentials and I can't even get postman to work with it.

I'm also going to be using AFNetworking if someone has used that with it as well.

Comment: If you look around the internet you'll find [THIS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/85528/user-accounts-ios-ruby-rails-swift) which should answer your question

Comment: Actually even better https://github.com/jaekwangseo/User-Authentication-in-Swift2

Comment: Yeah I saw the first one but possibly didn't look well enough. I shall check out the second and relook at the first thank you @Cyzanfar!